# What is this Ruby function doing?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am confused on how this returns:

```
def utc2user(t)
  ENV["TZ"] = current_user.time_zone_name 
  res = t.getlocal 
  ENV["TZ"] = "UTC"
  res
end
```

It first sets the ENV variable, then sets 'res' to the local value, then re-assignes ENV variable, then returns res?

Not sure I understand how this is convering from UTC to the user time zone?

Comment: Some info: http://wiki.rubyonrails.org/howtos/time-zones

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The first line is setting the environmental time zone variable to the user's time zone in order to get the `res` value in the correct time for that user. If it didn't set it to the user's, the time would still be in UTC.

It then sets the environmental variable back to UTC time, which I assume is the application's default.

It then returns `res`.

Answer (score 4):

The `getlocal` method *uses* ENV["TZ"], so this is just a little dance to temporarily set it, use it, and then put it back.

Although in this case it's being put "back" to "UTC", not what it was before, which seems a little dubious. And there's an `in_time_zone` method for doing this directly, anyway!

Answer (score 2):

It returns the time according to the time zone name specified by `current_user.time_zone_name` by invoking `getlocal` on the passed-in `Time` object.

It then resets the current time zone to UTC and returns the `Time` object returned from `getlocal` **at the time of that invocation** (i.e. when the environment's time zone was whatever the user's time zone is).

Answer (score 2):

This function takes the time as the input, it passes the users timezone to the TZ so that when the getlocal method is called it actually gets the time based on the user local timezone andnot on UTC. It then reverts back the TZ envt variable back to UTC and actually returns the users local time zone in the last line.